# Adding Filter Conditionally Per Page ID

Tags: filters, conditional-tags

I've created a function to add a class to the body, however if should only apply to a single page ID. This normally wouldn't be a problem, but it is breaking the layout for other pages.

**Filter Function**

```
add_filter('body_class','add_blog_to_body_class');

function add_blog_to_body_class($classes) {
    $classes[] = 'blog';
        return $classes;
}
```

**My Condition (that isn't working)**

```
function add_blog_to_body_class($classes) {
    $classes[] = 'blog';
    if ( is_page('ID') ) {
        return $classes;
    }
}
```

I've wrapped the entire function, the declaration, the `add_filter` hook, and everything without luck.

How can I have this function work on a single page ID?

Comment: I trust 'ID' in the condition is actually a page slug or so? And if the condition is not met, your filter is not returning anything.

Comment: You are correct. I put `ID` as a place holder. I'm working on page ID 40 :)

Comment: The filter is working, the condition isn't and it's breaking body classes on single posts pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important to **always return the value** in filter callbacks, otherwise it's like adding the  `__return_null()` callback.

Here's an example that adds the `blog` class only to page with ID 40:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_blog_to_body_class' );

function add_blog_to_body_class( $classes )
{
    if ( is_page( 40 ) )
        $classes[] = 'blog';

    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: you're welcome, I guess it's like plumming, we must keep the water flowing through the pipes ;-) @Jarmerson